# What is main purpose of filter in YII?

Tags: yii, yii-filters

As as title clarifies what is main purpose of filters in Yii? I am newbie to Yii and little confuse about filters and validators? Any one can explain it for me?

Answer (score 7):

A validator will be validating that an attribute in a model is as it should be: an, integer, a date, less than a given size, ...

Example:

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
        //username and password are required
        array('username, password', 'required'),
        //myInt is a number between 0 and 255
        array('myInt', 'numerical', 'min'=>0, 'max'=> 255),
    );
}
```

The validation rules will be tested when calling `$model->validate()` or `$model->save()`. If one of the validator did not pass, then an error will be thrown to the user.

You can know the errors thrown by calling `$model->getErrors()`

Source: [Model Rules Validation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh16)

The filter definition is :

> A filter can be applied before and after an action is executed. It can
>   modify the context that the action is to run or decorate the result
>   that the action generates.

So basiclly it will execute some work before calling the controller method (so before rendering anything on the screen) or after the controller is done (so it could be after the datas are validated and added in the db).
As example we can say:

- Check user authorizations
- Implements HTTP caching
- ...

To apply filters to actions, we need to override the CController::filters() method. The method should return an array of filter configurations. For example,

```
public function filters()
{
    return array(
       'postOnly + edit, create',
        array(
            'application.filters.PerformanceFilter - edit, create',
            'unit'=>'second',
        ),
    );
}
```

Using the plus and the minus operators, we can specify which actions the filter should and should not be applied to. In the above, the `postOnly` filter will be applied to the `edit` and `create` actions, while `PerformanceFilter` filter will be applied to all actions EXCEPT `edit` and `create`. If neither plus nor minus appears in the filter configuration, the filter will be applied to all actions.

Source: [Yii API about CFilter](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CFilter) and [Yii Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/basics.controller#filter)

So if you want to validate some datas, then use the validators and if what you want to do is not depending on the model (ie check a user is logged in, ...) then you should implements a filter.
In general the difference between a filter and a validator is pretty obvious.

Comment: Thanks for clear answer. I got it and one more question. Does filters call implicitly?

Comment: Added the answer of your question to my post. If you want to know more about filters (how to create one in its own class or in the controller class, ...), You should check the yii guide (see my link above), it's really well explained! (my example comes from it)

Answer (score 3):

Validators are used for preventing inserting or updating wrong data in db. Filters could be used to make some preparation before or after validating

```
class LoginForm extends CFormModel
{
    public $mail;
    public $password;
    public $rememberMe;

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
            array('mail, password', 'filter'=>'trim'),
            array('mail', 'filter'=>'mb_strtolower'),
            array('mail, password', 'required'),
            array('mail', 'email'),
            array('rememberMe', 'boolean'),
            array('password', 'authenticate'),
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Filters**  is mainly used to filter your URL. Here also included accessControl. That's means when you set URL to access any action. Then those filter checked that action is permitted for those User or not. Also if you set that this controller delete action only can be accessible by POST method Then you will not be able to delete by using GET method. Those all type of access .... Controlled by FILTERS.

On the other hand, **Validator** is used to validate your any input filed AS your wishes. As like Minimum , Maximum, Integer or not, is it will be Unique or not, is this field required or not. is this field will be email type or not ...... and many more type of validation of INPUT FIELD.....

In Single Word it can be say " **Validator is used for Input Validation and Filter is Used for Output Validation** "